# plist file in PSChildPaneSpecifier

Tags: iphone

I have created a settings bundle in my app and in that bundle, I have added a PSChildPaneSpecifier. For File key of this specifier, the value is the name of a plist file that I have added in the Settings bundle. Now, I want to edit that new plist file as per my needs so that I can display my content. How would I edit it?

Comment: I got it. The plist file we create to display in PSChildPaneSpecifier should be same as the one we edit when we create settings.bundle for our app,that is, Root.plist file. If you want to display something under child pane specifier, like About tha app or Terms and Conditions, then you can use the specifier PSGroup in new plist file.